# simplify a division with common matrices forming numerator and denumerator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a division of the kind
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x' A b}{ y' A b}
\end{equation*}
where $x$, $y$ and $b$ are vectors of length $k$ and $A$ is a square matrix $k\cdot k$. Is there a way to express this in terms of $x$ and $y$ only?

I see I can express this as $(x' A b)( b' A y)^{-1}$, but as inverses of vectors do not exist, it does not seem really helpful.

Comment: if $b$ is fixed, a simpler issue is to look for $\frac{x'u}{y'u}$ where $u:=Ab$. But I don't see a simpler way to express it.

Comment: yes, $b$ is fixed. I did not define a variable for $Ab$ hoping this distinction was of any use, but probably it is not heh

Comment: We can without loss of generality assume that $u$ has unit norm (if necessary by dividing numerator and denominator of $r:=\frac{x'u}{y'u}$ by $||u||$). You may know that $|x'u|$, in this case, is the "length" of the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto the axis defined by $u$. Therefore ratio $|r|$ is the ratio of two orthogonal projections onto the same axis, that's all...